# Safari on iPod window dimensions

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, ipod

i am developing a webapp for iOS that needs precise information about the window dimension.

on iPad and iPhone the window dimensions queried with jQuery in  are correct.

```
$(self.top).resize(function(e) {
  $(window).width();
  $(window).height();
}
```

however on iPod (4g) the reported dimension in portrait mode is 320 by 306 which is clearly wrong.

does anyone know why this is? is it intended? is it so on all iPods?

is it possible that iPod is reporting the dimension as to before it was rotated and not the new orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (window.innerWidth)
    return window.innerWidth;
else if (document.all) 
    return document.body.clientWidth;
```